# Standard Signature a Text in a Message using Exchange Server

Tags: outlook, exchange-server

Anyone know how to do this without using a third party program?  If there no way to do it with a add-on someone can recommend one?

EDIT: I need to add this in the server so all users have the same signature.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create your own exchange message sink to do this. Here's a classic VB example from MS KB:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317327

and a VB Script one:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317680

And lots of goodness from MSDN about Exchange 2003 Transport Event Sinks:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms526223(EXCHG.10).aspx

If you're running Exchange 2007 then you can use Transport Rules:

http://msexchangeteam.com/archive/2006/12/12/431879.aspx

http://www.msexchange.org/tutorials/Using-Transport-Rules-Creating-Disclaimers-Exchange-Server-2007.html

Answer (score 0):

We used [CodeTwo-s](http://codetwo.com/) Exchange rules for a while on Exchange 2003.

However there is a known problem with it: if the messages stay in the queue for 2-3 minutes, the Exchange itself sends out the message without the footer. Most of the times it's not a problem, but we have something like 700 people in our organization. If there are a lot of emails and some of them contains attachments, then the virus scanner stops them for a while (MS Antigen).

Otherwise it's a perfect solution if you have a smaller group of users to manage.

From other point of view: our users like to have some kind of control over the signature. We generated them and put it to their Outlooks. They like it that they know and see that the signature is there and how it looks like.